# How to allocate one half of an OpenCL buffer on host memory and the other half on device memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, opencl

If I understand it correctly, I can use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR when allocating CL buffer for the access of host memory from device kernel execution. I can use CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR for copying data to device memory. My question is: can I somehow allocate an array A with half of it allocated in host memory and the other half allocated in device memory. Say the first half is allocated in host memory. A[0~(N/2-1)] accesses host memory and A[N/2~(N-1)] accesses device memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The real truth is that you can't know where the memory is**.

The object memory allocated is inside an OpenCL "context", wich is purely virtual and can be anywhere (devices or host).
You can only specify to the OpenCL if you want the memory to be taken from a pointer, or copied from a pointer, or allocated a copy in the host. However, none of these guarantees at any time the memory consistency on the host side. That is, the memory you have on the host might not be the last version of that memory object. Since OpenCL allows the memory to be cached in the device(s).

Some vendors specify that some flags are used in their implementations and SDK to select between different types of memory (ie: pinned). But that is implementation dependant, and does not change the fact that you still need to use clReadBuffer() or clMapBuffer() to ensure that the value on the host side is the real output of your kernel.

From my personal experience, if you do not use heavy I/O. You can simply go with a CL_MEM_READ_WRITE flag.